# How to design databases?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-design

Describe the process in steps, please. What tools do you use for it?

Comment: Not a clear question. Exactly like "how do you build a car"? The answer is too big to fit in our site's style. See [here](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-kind-of-questions-are-allowed-on-database-administrators) what kind of questions are expected on [DBA_SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: If you don't know much about it, I can strongly recommend to read the book **"Beginning Database Design"** by *Clare Churcher*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with ["database design"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design) on Wikipedia.

I'd also recommend using [Object Role Modelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_role_modeling) to capture your [conceptual model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_schema)

Otherwise, your question is far too broad.

What you **don't** do is start knocking out some CREATE TABLE statements, or design as go along writing client side code